# Travelling to Tokyo in 6 days and my passport has been torn

Tags: passports, airports

Is this damage that would stop me being able to leave the country? Damage has happened today, I currently reside in the UK and have just had this tear happen.

[image]

Comment: I rolled back the removal of the photograph. All the personal information has been blacked out so I don't think there's any problem with it being here. If there is something that I missed, then you should ask the moderators to remove it from the edit history (use the "flag" link to get their attention) and replace it with a textual description of the damage.

Answer (score 4):

No one can be sure whether this level of damage will be acceptable. Your passport will first be checked by the airline. If they believe it is too damaged, you won't be allowed to board. Your passport will then be checked at the Japanese border. Again, if the level of damage is deemed unacceptable, you can be rejected and sent back. I believe the former scenario is much more likely than the latter.

Unfortunately, 6 days is just a little less time than you can guarantee a replacement before your trip. You aren't eligible for the same day premium service, since that's only for renewals. You would have to use the [1 week Fast Track service](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently/1-week-fast-track-service). If you apply **immediately** you probably have a decent chance of getting the passport back in time, but obviously it can't be guaranteed.

Comment: Sadly haven't got the means to pay for a new passport.

Well this is going to be a stressful week.

Comment: That level of damage will attract the attention of border guards. You should count on going to secondary at whatever country you travel to, and spending at least a few hours there while they validate the document and give you a thorough grilling. I would scrape up the money from somewhere, somehow, and contact the Passport Adviceline on 0300 222 0000 to find out if I could use the premium service to get a same day replacement.

Comment: Sadly, I’ve contacted and I would only be elegible for the fast tracked week wait as it’s damaged.  By secondary do you mean a second flight? I am unfamiliar with these terms, my apologies.

Comment: The term "secondary" means (in this type of situation) a more detailed interview with an Immigration Officer. Most passengers are cleared straight through "primary" (the first Immigration line you reach). If there is more to your circumstances than normal, you'll be required step out of line and go to a waiting/seating area. From there you'll eventually have a more detailed interview, bag search and document check. If all's in order you'll be "landed" ie allowed to proceed. If all is not well the outcome could be being "refused leave to enter" and being returned to whence you cam.

Comment: @DanielMaloney "secondary" is short for "secondary inspection," which in this case would be secondary immigration inspection (which can in some countries be separate from secondary customs inspection).  In any event, it is as canonacer describes.

Comment: what exactly is the damage? Can't see anything. Is it just the edge of the page? That looks like normal wear and tear to me.

Comment: @greatone The page is pretty clearly torn. And unfortunately, it's one from the spread which forms the ID page of the passport.

Comment: Okay, that was bad news I wasn't expecting.

I'm currently weighing up the pro's and cons of just cutting my losses, and cancelling this trip. It is a shame as it's the dream holiday, but that's my fault.

Comment: @MJeffryes It must be my screen. Do you refer to the edge just above the chip symbol? The UK Gov website does mention the page laminate lifting enough to allow a substitute as damage. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/damaged-and-faulty-passports/damaged-and-faulty-passports-policy However, I would not think a minor tear such as this could be seen as anything other than "wear and tear."

Comment: Going to see if I can refund the holiday partially, and just minimise the amount I lose.

If I can recoup something from the £2000 it's cost at least. It's a costly mistake. I'll remember to look after my passport next time.

Comment: @DanielMaloney If I were in your situation I would chance it, especially if the holiday is mostly non-refundable. I would say that if you are let on the aircraft, the chance of being rejected in Japan is quite low.

Comment: @greatone That's the definition of damaged as far as the UK government is concerned with regard to passport renewal. Other countries can have their own policies about foreigner's passports which could be more conservative, not to mention airline policies.

Comment: @Daniel Maloney I've seen passports with worse damage and airline staff or immigration officers don't bat an eye. They've seen all sorts of stuff. Why not go to an airport (before flying out) and show it to airline staff and if possible to immigration staff? Even if the decision is going to be made by Japanese officers, UK immigration officers' experience and insights into what to expect would be valuable.

Comment: @MJeffryes would they renew a passport that I think is damaged but they don't?

Comment: @greatone Yes, but once again, that wouldn't be eligible for the one day premium service, since that's only applicable to imminently expiring or already expired passports. Also, I disagree that you should call attention to the damage to airline staff. I think this is asking for trouble.

Comment: @MJeffryes They only renew passports if they're full/expiring or close expiring. They only replace damaged passports if they're actually damaged/lost/stolen. What I am suggesting is going to the airport at a different time to a different airline (preferably at a different terminal), explain your situation and ask them to examine the damage. It's better than asking strangers on the internet based on a blurry picture.

Comment: Just wanted to let everyone know, I'm back from Tokyo. I had a wonderful time and the passport didn't even get as much as a second glance. I'm now getting a replacement sorted for next year.

Thanks for the help guys.